# update mysql query from a batch file

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

Basically my batch file contains:

```
mysql -u root -pMypassword use myTableDB update myTable set extracted='Y'
```

but for some syntax error it doesn't update the table. However, when i run through command line:

```
mysql -u root -pMypassword use myTableDB
mysql update myTable set extracted='Y'
```

through command line it works. Anyone can point me what syntax error i have on the batch file.

Comment: Would that first command work if you typed it into the command line?

Comment: @SomethingDark, it doesn't work and it does not throw any error besides  Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]

Comment: Do the two separate commands work when you put them in the batch file?

Comment: @SomethingDark, it doesn't either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way would be the following:

```
mysql -u root -pMypassword -DmyTableDB -ANe"update myTable set extracted='Y'"
```

or if you want the SQL command placed in a variable, you could do this

```
set sqlstmt=update myTable set extracted='Y'
mysql -u root -pMypassword -DmyTableDB -ANe"%sqlstmt%"
```

Here is an example i just ran

```
set sqlstmt=show databases
mysql -u root -pMypassword -DmyTableDB -ANe"%sql%"
```

and I got this

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> set sqlstmt=show databases
C:\WINDOWS\system32> mysql ... -ANe"%sql%"
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
|              mysql |
| performance_schema |
|               test |
+--------------------+

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Answer (score 1):

mysql client reads SQL commands from STDIN. To do what you want, you would have to do something like the following in your batch file:

```
echo "update myTable set extracted='Y'" | mysql -u root -pMypassword myTableDB
```